# Run action in loop until or finished with success

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an epic which is trigger when the user updates data about his video. The user has a single page with multiple videos on it and can do update title on any chosen video. At bottom of the page there is *Submit* and when the user clicks it I need to save changes to all video so I dispatch action *saveVideo*. This action is triggering epic which will send a request and on success should trigger next pending video on the list to be saved.

Epic:

```
const updateVideoEpic = action$ => 
          action$.ofType(videoTypes.UPDATE_VIDEO_REQUEST)
                 .switchMap(action =>  Observable.from(updateVideo(action.payload)))
                 .takeUntil(action$.ofType(videoTypes.UPDATE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CANCEL))
                 .map(video => videoAction.updateVideoSuccess(video))
                 .catch((error) => Observable.of(videoAction.updateVideoFailure(error)));
```

How I can trigger asynchronous epic so after success updating data of 1st video will trigger again the same epic to update data for next video.

I thought about creating another epic but how you check if everything passed.
*Sudo code:*

```
const updateVideos = action$ => 
          action$.ofTypes(videoTypes.UPDATE_VIDEO_BATCH_REQUEST)
                 .switchMap(action => action.payload.videos)
                 .map(video => videoAction.updateVideoBatchRequest(video));
```

Comment: Did you look into the `withLatest()` operator?

Answer (score 0):

I change a little bit of approach and decided to use only fetch and loop though requests:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { mergeMap, catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip';

const urls = [
  { url: 'https://bbc.co.uk', name: 'BBC'},
  { url: 'https://google.com', name: 'Google'},
  { url: 'https://amazon.com', name: 'Amazon'}
];

const items$ = from(urls).pipe(
  mergeMap(item => fetch(item.url, {mode: 'no-cors'}))
)
items$.subscribe(
  url => console.log(url),
  error => console.log(error),
  () => console.log('Complete')
);
```

Working copy:
[Working copy on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zyah9m)